# Kernel error: hdaudio no AFG or MFG node found

Tags: 16.04, kernel

During boot on my laptop (running 16.04, all packages updated) I get hdaudio errors about `no AFG or MFG node found`.  The sound works, and I'm not sure what this error is trying to tell me.  From `syslog`:

```
Jul  8 06:31:34 laptop kernel: [   32.791352] hdaudio hdaudioC1D0: no AFG or MFG node found
Jul  8 06:31:34 laptop kernel: [   32.791388] hdaudio hdaudioC1D1: no AFG or MFG node found
Jul  8 06:31:34 laptop kernel: [   32.791420] hdaudio hdaudioC1D2: no AFG or MFG node found
Jul  8 06:31:34 laptop kernel: [   32.791450] hdaudio hdaudioC1D3: no AFG or MFG node found
```

Any help clearing these errors would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These error messages come from the HDA audio codec base device initialization. AFG is the audio function group, MFG is the modem function group.  Looking at the driver, one gets an -ENODEV (error, no device) error return from this, so I'm surprised audio still works.